# A nice formula for an integral of an increasing step function

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a monotone increasing sequence with $a_0=0$. Define the following function $f_{a_n}:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$:
$$f_{a_n}(x)=\begin{cases}k&a_k\le x<a_{k+1}\end{cases}$$

For $0\le a\le b$, can you think of a nice formula for the following integral?
$$\int_a^b f_{a_n}(x) dx$$

The only thing I could think of is a sum with conditional indicators, but that looks pretty messy.

**edit:** I'm not going to define *nice*... It's your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the notation $x^+=\max(x,0)$ is nice. The   function $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x-a_n)^+$ is an antiderivative of your $f$, and therefore
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg( (b-a_n)^+ - (a-a_n)^+ \bigg)
$$

Comment: I like your solution very much. It seems that $F(x)$ is not everywhere differentiable, so I am wondering in what sense it is really the antiderivative; however, it doesn't look like it matters in this case.

Comment: @Bach For an integrable (not necessarily continuous) function such as your $f=f_{a_n}$, the natural notion of antiderivative is: an [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) function $F$ such that $F'=f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!